# Regex file name with multiple digits

Tags: files, filenames, wildcards

Say I have the following file:

```
test_file-1234-master.tar.gz
```

I have tried to un `tar` using the following commands

```
 tar -xf test_file-[0-9]+-master.tar.gz
 tar -xf test_file-[:digit]-master.tar.gz
```

But no luck. How to match this pattern ?

**NOTE:** There will be always one file. I'm not trying to open multiple files.

Comment: shells do globbing, not regex.  see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64067/regex-match-in-cli

Comment: to answer your question, you want: `test_file-[0-9]*-master.tar.gz`

Comment: @cas This will match **one** digit followed by anything.

Comment: yes, so it will.  `test_file-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-master.tar.gz` then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `ksh`, `bash -O extglob` and `zsh -o kshglob` only:

```
test_file-+([[:digit:]])-master.tar.gz
```

In `bash`, you have to set the [`extglob`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) option first. This `+(...)` matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns. `[:digit:]` when inside a `[...]` bracket expression is a POSIX defined [character class](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07_03_01) which includes Indo-Arabic decimal digits (`[[:digit:]]` is the same as `[0123456789]` or `[0-9]`).

It will match:

```
test_file-1234-master.tar.gz
test_file-1-master.tar.gz
test_file-123456789-master.tar.gz
```

It will **not** match:

```
test_file-1b-master.tar.gz
test_file--master.tar.gz
test_file-a1-master.tar.gz
test_file-abcd-master.tar.gz
test_file-Ⅵ-master.tar.gz # roman numeral
test_file-٨-master.tar.gz  # Eastern Arabic decimal digit
```

---

The `tar` command in your question should then be done like this (with a loop):

```
shopt -s extglob # bash
# setopt kshglob # zsh
for f in test_file-+([[:digit:]])-master.tar.gz; do
    tar xf "$f"
done
```

The more idiomatic short syntax in `zsh` is:

```
setopt extendedglob
for f (test_file-[0-9]##-master.tar.gz) tar xf $f
```

(`#` being the extendedglob equivalent of regexp `*`, and `##` or `+`).

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to use extended regular expression metacharacters and POSIX character classes (`+` and `[:digit:]` respectively) in a globbing pattern;

Assuming `bash` or similiar, "basic" globbing only supports a handful of wildcards such as:

- `?`: single charater
- `*`: zero or more characters
- `[]`: character class
- `{}`: list
- `[!]`: negated character class

Differently from metacharacters in extended regular expressions, in "basic" globbing there's no way to modify a wildcard's behavior to match a fixed number of occurences;

So, using "basic" globbing, the shortest and tightest pattern would be:

```
tar -xf test_file-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-master.tar.gz
```